Can you use existing in home coax cables to connect a Leaf antenna to TV?
We would like to cancel Xfinity TV at my Mom's house. She has coax cables throughout her house. I bought a Mohu Leaf antenna to attach to the window to view local TV. I understand that the Leaf should be placed in a south facing window. The TV is in the north side of the house. I wanted to use the existing cable setup throughout the house to attach the Leaf to the south window and then to Mom's TV. Can this be done? If not does anyone have other suggestions on how to make this work?

The cable should work.  You want direct line from the antenna to the tv.  You loose a tiny bit of signal at every joint/spliter.  You want to check that the new antenna can receive the local channels first.  https://www.tvfool.com/interactive/   has good maps showing what you can receive at your/Mom's house plus the distance/antenna type needed.

Leaf should be placed in a south facing window ... how do you know this?

@crip659 You lose a lot of power at each splitter, it is divided evenly to each port regardless of if anything is connected. A two way splitter would cut the power in half, and a three way into a third. Also they can not be fed backwards.

Yes, you can use the existing coaxial cables to connect your antenna to the TV.
Ideally you want a cable that goes directly from where your antenna will be over to where the TV is, but you could use a barrel connector to join 2 cables together elsewhere if necessary. It's important to use high quality connectors and try to keep the cable as short as possible.
Mohu Leaf has amplifiers available to boost the signal, which will help with reception if you have to use long cables. The cable included with some of the amplified Leaf antennae I found is 16 feet, as a baseline.

To give some numbers to it, you can calculate the signal loss if you know the frequency, cable type and cable length.  Cable type is printed on the cable, something like 'RG-6'.  Airwave TV in USA is 216 MHz and below, or 700MHz and below for UHF.  Using an online calculator, I see 100ft of RG-6 cable loses 4.2dB (38% makes it to the end) at 216MHz.

This is a rookie questions, but where do I find high quality connectors?

Probably varies by region. Here in midwest US, I'd try to get some from the Cable company (I actually have several from previous house installs) and then try Microcenter... Best Buy if there's nothing else around. I've gotten good cheap cables from Monoprice online too. You could get lucky with Amazon, Aliexpress, or any other e-tailer, but they have reputations for poor quality so they wouldn't be my first choice if you have other options.

The instructions for the Mohu Leaf say to connect the coax cable from the antenna to the "ANT IN" (antenna in?) of the TV then switch the TV input to "Antenna" or "Air" mode.
That sounds like good ol' TV reception to me. In-house coax was able to do that back in the day, to get the antenna signals to the TV wherever it was.
You may need to hunt through the coax cables in your house to remove splitters in the line going from the cable at the antenna to the cable at the TV and replace them with one-cable-to-one-cable couplers, so the signal doesn't degrade going off to other rooms. Or the antenna may work just fine with your in-house coax as is.

Would be nice if they took out the ads, if I pay I don't want ads, if one month will pay for a good antenna.

I will go in the attic to search for the cables and any splitters.

I do not know about south/north orientation, it will depend where is the local tv broadcast tower.
Find out where it is.
Usually it does work better with line of sight.
As for the coax it will work.
